# Log analytics query optimization

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

I run this query on log analytics

```
                                        Perf
                                        | where TimeGenerated >= ago(5m) 
                                        | join kind = inner
                                            ( 
                                                Heartbeat  
                                                | where TimeGenerated >= ago(5m)
                                                | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) 

                                                by SourceComputerId
                                            ) on Computer
                                        | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by SourceComputerId, CounterName
                                        | extend  Indicator = strcat(ObjectName,'-', CounterName)
                                        | summarize dict = make_dictionary
                                        (   
                                            pack
                                            (      
                                                  'WorkspaceId' 
                                                ,  TenantId
                                                ,  Indicator       
                                                ,  CounterValue
                                                ,  'TimeGenerated'   
                                                ,  TimeGenerated
                                                ,  'Computer'
                                                ,  Computer
                                            )
                                        )  by SourceComputerId
                                        | evaluate bag_unpack(dict)
```

But it's a little bit slow. Is there any way to optimize it, I want the fastest possible query to achieve the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somewhat challenging to say without you mentioning the size of the data (e.g. record count) for each of the `join` legs and the cardinality of the `SourceComputerId` column.

I would recommend that you go over the [query best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/best-practices#join-operator) document which covers several techniques for optimization, and see if that helps

**Update: Explicitly mentioning best practices which may be helpful in your case: (for you to verify)**

- When using join operator - choose the table with less rows to be the first one (left-most).
- When left side is small (up to 100,000 records) and right side is big then it is recommended to use the hint.strategy=broadcast.
- When both sides of the join are too big and the join key is with high cardinality, then it is recommended to use the hint.strategy=shuffle.
- When the group by keys of the summarize operator are with high cardinality (best practice: above 1 million) then it is recommended to use the hint.strategy=shuffle.

Comment: The cardinality of SourceComputerId column can go up to 300K (machines).  and for the Perf table, you know it's updated for each machine with a new record given a certain frequency (default is 10s).

Comment: thanks. do the query best practices help you understand potential room for optimization for `join` and `summarize`?

Comment: Assuming that those time filters will lower the number of records in each of  the tables in the join to a  number less than 1 million . Suppose Perf after time-filter will contain 600k and Heartbeat  300k after the time filter.
What are the optimisation that can be applied for join and summarize in this configuration ?

Comment: and Yes I applied some of the best practices guidelines.  I moved heartbeat table to the left of the join as it contains fewer records than Perf (after time filtering).

Comment: can you please provide some guidance, I provided cardinal of tables participating in this join ?

Comment: I've included the ones i think are relevant (pasted from the docs) in an update to my reply